# Disabling window onbeforeunload function in a link

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, popup, onbeforeunload

i have a site using  window onbeforeunload function but popup on click is not working because of it. how can i integrate the code

```
window.onbeforeunload="null";
```

in the popup code below

```
 <script type='text/javascript'>

    function ouvre(fichier) {
          ff=window.open(fichier,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%")     //this._try = 1;            setTimeout('this._try = 1;', 4000);   }   function playMovie(_try) {      if (this._try == 1) { playlavideo(); }      else { alert('You must share the video to play.'); }        }


     </script>

<a href="#" onClick="ouvre('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com/');return false"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GnqwI.jpg" width="500" height="145" border="0"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be working, with the key change being placing `window.onbeforeunload=null` before opening the link.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  // Set a beforeunload callback
  window.onbeforeunload = function() { return false; };

  function open_popup(url) {
    window.open(url,"popup","width=600px,height=300px,left=50%,top=50%");
    return false;
  }
</script>
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http://google.com/" onClick="window.onbeforeunload=null;return open_popup(this.href);"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/GnqwI.jpg" width="500" height="145" border="0"></a>
```

Comment: I updated the answer with a version which works for me, can you try again?

Comment: I tried using   `target="_blank;"` its working fine but it not openeing popup instead of it opening in new full page window